# library for multidimensional arrays in bash

Tags: bash

i need multidimensional arrays in bash, i wrote myself a function, but it is too slow,
is there a library outthere for faster array access.

For creating 1000 entries of childarrays in the parent array and then reading out the child array's first element, all through,
i need 0.157s
`time { for ((i=0;i<1000;i++)); do arrOFarr test create $i "ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab"; done; for index in ${!test_arrOFarr[*]}; do arrOFarr test get $index; echo $arrOFarr_item; done }`

i have this function:

```
#!/bin/bash

#-- call:        arrOFarr [array basename STR] [action STR] [index INT] [action additional argument STR or bINT] 
#-- description: allows arrays of arrays as items. the parent array is an indexed array, the child array can be an associative or indexed array.
#-- parameters:  $1 ... array basename STR - the basename of the parent array, the array is set in the shell parameters with "_arrOFarr" addition to the basename
#                                            created items (child arrays) of the parent array are set with "_arrOFarr_item_"(unique number) addition
#--              $2 ... action STR - the type of action
#--                                     In the following examples test is the basename of the parent array and so it is set in shell parameters as "test_arrOFarr"
#--                                     create  ... creates an indexed array, with the item string, overhanded as action argument
#--                                                 and adds it to the parent array at index position. If the parent array doesnt exists yet, it will be created!
#--
#--                                                     arrOFarr test create 0 "hello bello cello dello"                             unquoted items
#--                                                     arrOFarr test create 1 '"hello" "bello" "*" "?"'                             quoted items - prohibit file globbing
#--                                                     $varname="hello_bello_cello"; IFS="_" arrOFarr test create 2 '$varname'      items by word splitting
#--
#--                                                 the indexed array are set in the shell parameters as "test_arrOFarr_item_"(unique number)
#--                                                 Attention: if word splitting is used, use set -o noglob to prohibit that data characters * ? [] are recognized as file patterns,
#--                                                            if these characters are in the action argument.
#--
#--                                     add     ... adds an already existing associative or indexed array to the parent array at index position, the variable name is overhanded in the action argument
#-- 
#--                                                     x=(ab bb bc); arrOFarr test add 3 x
#--                                      
#--                                     get     ... gets the items of the parent array at index position, the child_array is finally linked under shell parameter "arrOFarr_item" !!!!
#--                                                     arrOFarr test get 0  -- gets the item with index 0
#--                                                
#--                                     unset   ... unsets the item of the parent array at index position and unsets the linked child array in the shell parameters
#--                                                 or if index "-" unsets the complete arrOFarr parent array and its child arrays in the shell parameters
#--                                                     arrOFarr test unset 0   -- unsets an item of the parent array
#--                                                     arrOFarr test unset -   -- kills complete arrOFarr parent array
#--
#--                                     rewrite ... rewrites the parent array, removing empty places in the array
#--                                                     arrOFarr rewrite
#--                                                 
#--              $3 ... index INT - the array index of the parent array for the action
#--
#--              $4 ... action argument
#--                     create  - STR  ... the item string of the created indexed array - "hello bello cello dello" - examples see create
#--                     add     - STR  ... the variable name of the associative or indexed array to add
#--                     get     - not needed
#--                     unset   - not needed
#--                     rewrite - not needed  
#-- depends on: -
arrOFarr ()
    {
    #-- example array basename is test
    local arrOFarr_varname="${1}_arrOFarr"
    local -n arrOFarr_isSet="${arrOFarr_varname}_isSet"
    
    #-- check if arrOFarr is set, if not set it
    if ((${#arrOFarr_isSet}==0)); then
        declare -ga "${arrOFarr_varname}=()"                                                  #--added as test_arrOFarr to shell parameters
        declare -g "${arrOFarr_varname}_unique_counter=0" "${arrOFarr_varname}_isSet=true"    #--added as test_arrOFarr_unique_counter, test_arrOFarr_isSet to shell parameters
    fi

    local -n arrOFarr=$arrOFarr_varname arrOFarr_unique_counter="${arrOFarr_varname}_unique_counter"   #-- link the variables, arrOFarr ... parent array, arrOFarr_unique_counter ... as unique id for the name of child arrays
    local arrOFarr_childarray_basename="${arrOFarr_varname}_item_"                                     #-- becomes test_arrOFarr_item_
    
    case $2 in
        "create")
            arrOFarr_varname=$arrOFarr_childarray_basename$arrOFarr_unique_counter                     #-- arrOFarr varname redefined to child array varname, 
            declare -ga "$arrOFarr_varname=($4)"                                                       #-- child array added as test_arrOFarr_item_(uniqueID) to shell parameters
            arrOFarr[$3]=$arrOFarr_varname                                                             #-- the child array variabel name is set as item in the parent array
            ((arrOFarr_unique_counter++));;
        "add")
            arrOFarr[$3]=$4;;                                                                          #-- adds an existing associative or indexed array to the parent array
        "get")
            declare -gn arrOFarr_item=${arrOFarr[$3]};;                                                #-- links the child array to shell parameter arrOFarr_item
        "unset")
            if [[ $3 == "-" ]]; then
               unset "${arrOFarr[@]}" arrOFarr arrOFarr_unique_counter arrOFarr_isSet                  #-- unsets the complete parent array
            else
               unset ${arrOFarr[$3]} arrOFarr[$3]                                                     #-- unsets the child array in the shell parameters and unsets the name of the child array in the parent array
            fi;;
         "rewrite")
            arrOFarr=("${arrOFarr[@]}");;                                                              #-- rewrites the array killing empty indices
    esac
    }
```

Comment: If you need multidimensional arrays, bash and other shells are the wrong choice.

Comment: bash is mostly an unfinished clone of ksh. ksh93 does have multi-dimensional arrays and since bash syntax is mostly a subset of that of ksh93', switching to that shell shouldn't be too painful. But I'd agree switching to a proper programming languages would make a lot more sense.

Comment: _"i need multidimensional arrays in bash"_ No! Bad human, no!

Comment: can you not just build your arrays into a json object and use jq to work with them in bash?

Comment: Your function/example doesn't work for me and I don't really understand how you want your array to look

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I don't see a question in your question. Did you want https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? ... Oh, there it is: "is there a library outthere for faster array access" -- No is the answer.

Comment: @jesse_b i'm drawing some buttons on the terminal screen, each button has properties, line, column, width, height, bordercolor, backgroundcolor, activecolor, text, action.  These infos are stored in a button array, every button is than added to an button register array with arrOFarr. This register array is worked through in loops, checking if mouse coordinates are over a button, if so highlight, but im getting lags. Okay I think i skip highlighting.

Comment: @jesse_b "Your function/example doesn't work for me " -- changed that, i had a mistake in the for loop writing i==0; instead of i=0;

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza: no there are quoting issues in your function but even when I fixed them I still don't understand what it's supposed to do

Comment: @jesse_b lets say you have two arrays a=(1 2 3), b=(4 5 6),  and you write arrOFarr myvar add 0 a; arrOFarr myvar add 1 b, then it will create a new array called myvar_arrOFarr, where the 0 element is the name of array a "a", and the 1 element is the name of array b "b",  when you write arrOFarr myvar get 1, then it will link the global variable arrOFarr_item to array b;  and you get the e.g. second element of array b with ${arrOFarr_item[1]} that would be equal to ${b[1]}

Comment: Agree that if you must use a shell, look at ksh93+ (there numerous variants, old versions of ksh around, so make sure you're using the best version available OR get it installed. ALSO, as you seem to be interested in user interfaces, look at dtksh, (DeskTop KorrnShell), although I'm not sure if anyone is working on it AND it was originally targeted at the X windowing systems from the 80s-90s (also essentially abandonware )-; ),. Depending on the resources your organization can put into your project, you may at find it is at least a place to start. There is book about dtksh avail. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thx for your comment, i was look around for alternatives and found zenity, i can use that, they have some graphical interfaces for bash scripts

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza : Thanks for that info. I'm aware of Zenity, but have never looked at it. I think it will be better forr your project to use a tool that is still actively supports, so I hope it can do what you need. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, but the comments in your code at the top are very much a hassle to read, while your code is beautiful to read. Can you please un-indent everything between `$2 ... action STR &&  $3 ... index` ? Tnx.